# OpenGL Widget on QT doesn't display primitives

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

The class copied below serve to create an OpenGL context in a QT widget.

However it doesn't display any point while it works well when I use GLFW...

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include "shader.hpp"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) {

}

GLWidget::~GLWidget() {
    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glewInit();
    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    programID = LoadShaders("SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "ColorFragmentShader.fragmentshader");

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    MatrixID        = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    ModelMatrixID   = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");

    // Get a handle for our buffers
    vertexPosition_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition_modelspace");

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);


    // Temporary code for vertices and their color generation 
    vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0,0,0));  // A point situated at 0,0,0 for test 
    color.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    index.push_back(0);

    int size = 1000;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        vertices.push_back(glm::vec3((rand() % 100) / 10, (rand() % 100) / 10, (rand() % 100) / 10));
        color.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        index.push_back(i);
    }

    /*Computing the points centroid */
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        mx += vertices[i][0];
        my += vertices[i][1];
        mz += vertices[i][2];
    }

    mx = mx / vertices.size(); my = my / vertices.size(); mz = mz / vertices.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        vertices[i][0] = vertices[i][0] - mx;
        vertices[i][1] = vertices[i][1] - my;
        vertices[i][2] = vertices[i][2] - mz;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &color[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &index[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Line indexing, not in use actually....
    unsigned int indexL[] = { 1550, vertices.size() - 1300 };

    GLuint elementbufferLine;
    glGenBuffers(1, &elementbufferLine);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbufferLine);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * sizeof(unsigned int), &indexL[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); */
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    //glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(-5, -5, -5),                  // Camera is here
        glm::vec3(mx, my, mz),  // and looks here
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)                      // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );

    ModelMatrix         = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    ProjectionMatrix    = glm::perspective(glm::radians(80.0f), float(w) /float(h), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    MVP                 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    /* Using shaders */
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
    // in the "MVP" uniform
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    // Index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

    // Draw the point cloud !
    glPointSize(5);
    glDrawElements(
        GL_POINTS,              // mode
        index.size(),           // count
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,        // type
        (void*)0                // element array buffer offset
    );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe with your math, all vertices are created in a (0,0,0)-(9.9, 9.9, 9.9) range. Then you compute the centroid and subtract. lets say your mx, my, mz is (5.0, 5.0, 5.0). Now if you subtract the centroid, all your points are now in the range (-5.0, -5.0, -5.0) and (4.9, 4.9, 4.9).

In other words all you have done is center all your points to the origin. I believe you should be looking at the origin (0, 0, 0) not (5, 5, 5).